# How to reset a TeamCity build after stripping Hg changesets?

Tags: mercurial, build, teamcity

I recently needed to strip some changesets from my Mercurial repository. I then tried to run a build from TeamCity but got the following error message:

*[09:44:25]: Updating sources: agent side checkout... (16s)*

*[09:44:42]: [Updating sources: agent side checkout...] Failed to perform checkout on agent: 'cmd /c hg update -C -r 507b8c8f4cdb' command failed. stderr: abort: unknown revision '507b8c8f4cdb'!*

The error makes sense since the changeset no longer exists in the repo, but I don't know how to reset TeamCity to pull from the new tip. I'm guessing that I could copy the TeamCity build configuration to a new build, but then I'd lose my history.

Is this possible? Or have I corrupted my TeamCity build and need to start up a new one?

Comment: Add a new commit so tip gets updated

Comment: Yes. I tried that before running the build. No luck. I'm sure that TeamCity has the last changeset ID stored somewhere, but I haven't seen it from the UI.

Comment: Is this project linked via a snapshot dependency?

Comment: It does not have a snapshot dependency. I don't think adding a new changeset would work because TeamCity would still try to pull changes from the last known & stripped changeset id.

Comment: Oh so you haven't tried adding a new commit? If you update tip, TeamCity should pull from the new tip - it shouldn't care what the last known changeset is.

Comment: Sylvanaar - you are correct. Adding a new changeset fixed the issue. Do you know where TeamCity was getting the stripped changeset id from? I figured it must have stored it since it was using it even though I dropped the old VCS. Anyway, if you add your suggestion as the answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a new commit to the repository so that the tip revision gets updated.